# How can I access complex data (like children data) in the Rails index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing an Rails app that will display food with its nutrients. I want to show only the nutrients that the user wants to see.

So, I have the models:

- Food:
- Nutrient:
- FoodNutrient: Specifies the quantity of each nutrient in each food
- UserNutrient: Specifies which nutrients the user wants to see
  I will have thousands of foods and more than 100 nutrients

I saw several several sources that give hints on how to deal with this type of complexity (for now I'm considering in trying with Arel). However, these sources usually don't provide examples neither hints on how we should deal with this on the views. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691393/rails-presenting-complex-data-view) but would love more opinions on the issue, specially concerning the large data involved.

So, how is the best way to deal with this in my index view?

Another doubt that I have is if it is better for performance to have the FoodNutrient model or it is better to include columns on the Food model in which each new column would represent a nutrient. I suppose that the FoodNutrient bet is better as the user will choose which nutrients he will see but I'm not sure.
I would appreciate any example, explanation, advice, feedback or reference that may help me.

**Edited**

As there were some comments from people that didn't understand my question, I will try to summarize it in other words.

I want to get data from the first 3 models, and the last one (UserNutrient) I would use to reduce the number of rows shown to the user.

As I want to show something like:

```
Food Name  |  Nutrient 1  |  Nutrient 2  |  Nutrient 3
_______________________________________________________
Food 1        10             40             7.3
Food 2        9              4.4            9.1
```

I understand that I would have one loop on Food that would iterate one per row shown above. And I would also have to iterate on UserNutrient inside of the first loop to show the quantity of the nutrient on each food (this data is on UserNutrient). The main question is how to do these loops, specially considering that the tables will have lots of data. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691393/rails-presenting-complex-data-view) seems to be a little similar, although I didn't understand well.

My other doubt is if the structure is the best one. The FoodNutrient and Food tables could be merged.

Comment: do you have a mockup of how you'd like the data to be displayed?

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. I edited it. I hope that it is better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched about this problem and for now I'm decided to merge the FoodNutrient and Food tables/models as Food.
I believe that a FoodNutrient with lots of rows would be worse as it would have a huge index. Worse than a Food table with lots of columns.

This article helped me to decide:

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/58-select-specific-fields-for-performance

If you have something to add, please, answer the question too or add a comment.